# Getting timeout exception while connecting Jira to fetch issues

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, connection-timeout

I am getting below error in logs while fetching Jira issues on particular JQL. I have set a schedular to run that JQL every 30 mins to sync the retrieved issues to another tool.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:294)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:267)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:96)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:69)
    at com.asurion.Autopilot.main(Autopilot.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient$3.apply(DefaultHttpClient.java:256)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient$3.apply(DefaultHttpClient.java:249)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$2.apply(Promises.java:276)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$2.apply(Promises.java:272)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onFailure(Promises.java:167)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:801)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:262)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:149)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:193)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.setException(SettableFuture.java:68)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1$3.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:73)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:197)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:90)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:192)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1.doCancelled(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:67)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalContextAwareFutureCallback$3.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:152)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:90)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalContextAwareFutureCallback.cancelled(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:147)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.CachingHttpAsyncClient$2.cancelled(CachingHttpAsyncClient.java:636)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.cancel(BasicFuture.java:150)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultResultCallback.cancelled(DefaultResultCallback.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultAsyncRequestDirector.cancel(DefaultAsyncRequestDirector.java:533)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultAsyncRequestDirector$1.abortConnection(DefaultAsyncRequestDirector.java:222)
    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase.cleanup(HttpRequestBase.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase.abort(HttpRequestBase.java:151)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.base.RequestKiller$RequestEntry.abort(RequestKiller.java:98)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.base.RequestKiller.run(RequestKiller.java:56)
    ... 1 more
```

This error is occurring frequently but not continuous. Sometime it works, many times it won't.

```
Jira Version: 7.1.4#71008
Jira REST Java Client Version: 2.0.0-m2
JIRA REST java-client-core Version: 2.0.0-m25
```

Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Tushar

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a timeout on your request, which comes and goes depending on server load. Can you streamline or break up the query, set a longer timeout, or put other activity on the server on hold during the sync?

Comment: Hi Mike, Thank you for your input. Currently we have put the time of 20 mins. And the query generally returns not more than 20 issues per hit.

Comment: We have 3 type of timeouts set in our code options.setConnectionTimeout(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  options.setSocketTimeout(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  options.setConnectionPoolTimeToLive(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES); We get the resultset, but when we claim on the result then it throws concurrent timeout exception as mentioned in the question code error snippet

Comment: Hi Mike, we increased the timeout to **30 mins**. Still it is giving same error!

Comment: Okay, it sounds like that's not it, then. Maybe add the query to your question, there might be something amiss in it?

Answer (score 0):

There was some issue with Jira server. We don't have access to it, but after few days the issue seems to be gone. Not sure what has happened at Jira side.